# bin/console without working DB

Tags: doctrine-orm, symfony-3.2

I would like to be able to run symfony `php bin/console` without configured dbal.

I want to run some non-db related commands on CI without db.

Is it somehow possible?

Thanks.

Comment: Sure.  Are you getting an error of some sort?

Comment: @Cerad. Yes, when i do not configure DBAL i get, either, `You have requested a non-existent parameter` or when there is non-valid configuration i got something like `An exception occured in driver: timeout expired`

Comment: You can just use the default values and everything should be fine.  The command will not attempt to connect to the database unless you tell it to.  Otherwise, just remove DoctrineBundle from app/AppKernel.php and remove the config lines.  You can also just use the console component standalone without the framework at all.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As suggested by Cerad in his comment, you should remove the DoctrineBundle from AppKernel.php.

If you do need that bundle in other contexts for your app (e.g. accessing from a browser) than you could define a customized environment (e.g. `console`) and enable the bundle only in the other environments (prod, dev, test are the default). See https://symfony.com/doc/current/configuration/environments.html